# Get total of property when using pagedlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, pagedlist

I have the following code defined below, what I am trying to do is get the total of the following properties (ItemsRequireingAttention, NumberOfUrgentItems).

Although Model.Count tells me how many view models I have in my view model, I want to be able to get the total count of the 2 aforementioned properties.

I've tried using Model.TotalCountFor and Model.Where but don't seem to be able to get them to work. My current code below, will only tell me the totals for the subset that is currently in view. Is this possible or am I going to have to look into using partials

**PortalViewModel**

```
public class PortalViewModel
{
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
    public bool MotExpired { get; set; }
    public bool TaxExpired { get; set; }
    public bool MotWithin7Days { get; set; }
    public bool TaxWithin7Days { get; set; }
    public bool MotWithin30Days { get; set; }
    public bool TaxWithin30Days { get; set; }
    public bool MotNotRecorded { get; set; }
    public bool TaxNotRecorded { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfUrgentItems { get; set; }
    public int ItemsRequireingAttention { get; set; }

}
```

**PortalController**

```
public class PortalController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        var cookie = new HttpCookie("view", "admin"); 
        var portalViewModel = new List<PortalViewModel>();

        var vehicles = db.Vehicles.ToList();

        foreach (var vehicle in vehicles)
        {
            var vm = new PortalViewModel { Vehicle = vehicle };

            if (vehicle.MotDate == null)
            {
                vm.MotNotRecorded = true;
                vm.NumberOfUrgentItems++;
            }
            if (vehicle.TaxDate == null)
            {
                vm.TaxNotRecorded = true;
                vm.NumberOfUrgentItems++;
            }

            if (vehicle.MotDate <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1))
            {
                vm.MotExpired = true;
                vm.NumberOfUrgentItems++;
            }
            if (vehicle.TaxDate != null && DateTime.Now.Subtract((DateTime)vehicle.TaxDate).Days >= 7)
            {
                vm.TaxWithin7Days = true;
            }
            else if (vehicle.TaxDate != null && DateTime.Now.Subtract((DateTime)vehicle.TaxDate).Days >= 30)
            {
                vm.TaxWithin30Days = true;
            } 
            portalViewModel.Add(vm);
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities
@using PagedList
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@using WebApplication1.ViewModels
@model IPagedList<PortalViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
    var pagedList = (IPagedList)Model;
    var urgentItems = Model.Count(i => i.NumberOfUrgentItems >= 1); //(item => item.NumberOfUrgentItems >= 1);
    int flaggedItems = Model.Count(i => i.ItemsRequireingAttention >= 1);
    int vehicles = Model.Count();

}

<h2>Dashboard</h2>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    @if (urgentItems != 0)
    {
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="panel panel-back noti-box">
                <span class="icon-box bg-color-red set-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-warning"></i>
                </span>
                <div class="text-box">
                    <p class="main-text">@urgentItems Items</p>
                    <p class="text-muted">Requiring immediate action</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    @if (flaggedItems != 0)
    {
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="panel panel-back noti-box">
                <span class="icon-box bg-color-green set-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i>
                </span>
                <div class="text-box">
                    <p class="main-text">@flaggedItems Items</p>
                    <p class="text-muted"><br />Require attention</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="panel panel-back noti-box">
            <span class="icon-box bg-color-blue set-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-truck"></i>
            </span>
            <div class="text-box">
                <p class="main-text">@vehicles</p>
                <p class="text-muted"><br />Vehicles in fleet</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                <strong>Current Fleet Details</strong>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <div class="panel  panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title text-center">
                                <span class=" ">
                                    Click on the reference number to edit vehicle details
                                </span>
                                <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></span>
                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></span>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.First().Vehicle.RefNumber)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.First().Vehicle.Make)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.First().Vehicle.Model)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.First().Vehicle.Registration)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayName("Dates")</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr class='@if (item.MotNotRecorded || item.MotExpired || item.TaxNotRecorded || item.TaxExpired)
                                               {
                                                   @Html.Raw("danger")

                                               } else if (item.MotWithin30Days || item.MotWithin7Days || item.TaxWithin30Days || item.TaxWithin7Days)
                                               {
                                                   @Html.Raw("warning")
                                               }
                                               else
                                               {
                                                   @Html.Raw("success")
                                               }'>
                                    <td>
                                        @if (!item.Vehicle.RefNumber.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Vehicle.RefNumber))
                                        {
                                            @Html.ActionLink(item.Vehicle.RefNumber, "Edit", "Portal", new { @ref = item.Vehicle.RefNumber }, null)
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            @item.Vehicle.RefNumber
                                        }
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.Vehicle.Make
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.Vehicle.Model
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.Vehicle.Registration
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.Vehicle.MotDate):
                                        @{
                                if (item.MotNotRecorded)
                                {
                                    <span class="pull-right text-warning text-uppercase">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i>
                                        @string.Format("Not yet recorded")
                                    </span>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <span class="pull-right text-success">
                                        @string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item.Vehicle.MotDate) <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                    </span>
                                }
                                        }
                                        <br />
                                        @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.Vehicle.TaxDate)
                                        @{
                                if (item.TaxNotRecorded)
                                {
                                    <span class="pull-right text-warning text-uppercase">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i>
                                        @string.Format("Not yet recorded")
                                    </span>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <span class="pull-right text-success">
                                        @string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item.Vehicle.TaxDate) <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                    </span>
                                }
                                        }
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
                    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller method is missing a `return` statement, but I'm assuming that you are returning your `portalViewModel` list.

I would recommend creating a ViewModel which has an `IPagedList` of `PortalViewModel`'s and place the values you need in the containing ViewModel. Then you could use display templates in the view for each item.

However, you could also create two `int` variables and increment them in your `foreach` loop over the vehicles list, then put them into the ViewBag.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    var cookie = new HttpCookie("view", "admin");
    var portalViewModel = new List<PortalViewModel>();

    var vehicles = db.Vehicles.ToList();

    var totalNumberOfUrgentItems = 0; // first total
    var totalNumberOfItemsRequireingAttention = 0; // second total

    foreach (var vehicle in vehicles)
    {
        var vm = new PortalViewModel { Vehicle = vehicle };

        if (vehicle.MotDate == null)
        {
            vm.MotNotRecorded = true;
            vm.NumberOfUrgentItems++;
        }
        if (vehicle.TaxDate == null)
        {
            vm.TaxNotRecorded = true;
            vm.NumberOfUrgentItems++;
        }

        if (vehicle.MotDate <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1))
        {
            vm.MotExpired = true;
            vm.NumberOfUrgentItems++;
        }
        if (vehicle.TaxDate != null && DateTime.Now.Subtract((DateTime)vehicle.TaxDate).Days >= 7)
        {
            vm.TaxWithin7Days = true;
        }
        else if (vehicle.TaxDate != null && DateTime.Now.Subtract((DateTime)vehicle.TaxDate).Days >= 30)
        {
            vm.TaxWithin30Days = true;
        }

        totalNumberOfUrgentItems += vehicle.NumberOfUrgentItems;
        totalNumberOfItemsRequireingAttention += vehicle.ItemsRequireingAttention;

        portalViewModel.Add(vm);
    }

    ViewBag["TotalNumberOfUrgentItems"] = totalNumberOfUrgentItems;
    ViewBag["TotalNumberOfItemsRequireingAttention"] = totalNumberOfItemsRequireingAttention;
    // presumably your return statement is here
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Will, yes, I was returning a list of portalViewModel, I missed that when I was doing my copy and paste. I went with your suggestion of having a viewmodel which had an IPagedList which took in the other view model, not sure if that good code design but its sufficient for what I want currently and will do and till I get more up to speed with design patterns

Comment: I think you made the right choice! From personal experience, having strongly-typed references in Razor code makes maintenance easier down the road. With a ViewBag, you can sometimes end up wondering if you spelled the key wrong, or type casting problems.